# Need to hide an element depending on date and post category

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript

I've been racking my brains for a few days trying to figure this out. I'm using WP Voting on my site. I need to create a script in single.php that will remove the div that contains the voting widget depending on the date and the post category. For instance:

If the month is September and the category IS NOT 13, remove div

Else

If the month is October and the category IS NOT 14, remove div.

I tried this first with JavaScript which worked with the date, but not category, and then php, but I can't seem to get it right.

Can anyone help? Please?

Thanks

Ettan

Comment: what have you tried so far? Also, you need to use the post date or the current date?

Comment: If you want clear answer then you would like to ask question in detail and clear explanation. Please edit the question with more explanation. What output did you get? What were you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Drop this into the file that is displaying the date (assuming you are using [get_the_date](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_date)):

```
$month = date( 'F' );
$categoryIds = array();
$bannedMonth = 'September';
$bannedCategory = 13;
$categoryArray = get_the_category();
foreach ( $categoryArray as $categoryObj ) {
    array_push( $categoryIds, $categoryObj->term_id );
}
if ( $month != $bannedMonth && !in_array( $bannedCategory, $categoryIds ) ) {
    echo get_the_date();
}
```